# Java int cannot be converted to Double

Tags: java

Why the casting will cause the error? From my understanding, `int num` will be implicitly converted to `double`, but now to avoid this error, I need to do `temp.add((double) num);`

```java
public void test(int[] nums) {
        List<Double> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int num: nums) {
            temp.add(num);
        }

    }
```

Error:

```
Playground Debug 
Line 6: error: no suitable method found for add(int)
            temp.add(num);
                ^
    method Collection.add(Double) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to Double)
    method List.add(Double) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to Double)
```

Comment: Yes, `int` will be converted to `double`.  That does not mean it will be converted to `java.lang.Double`.  Boxing and promotion are two different steps.  They can’t both happen implicitly.

Comment: Sometimes when you run it on debug BEFORE running it on "normal run mode" this will happen, run it normal and then try debug

Comment: @VGR I see, and the reason why the following works is because it only has promotion one step right? `int i = 1; Double d = new Double(i);`

Comment: Yes, that’s correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a list of `Double`s, and you're trying to add an `int` to it...

This statement

```
temp.add(num);
```

Will first need to box `num` to its wrapper form, which is `java.lang.Integer`, before adding it to the list (because the list takes reference types, not primitives).

What happens next is that you're trying to add an `Integer` to a collection of `Double`s. And this is not allowed. `Integer` is not a subclass of `Double`. These are sibling types (they both are subclasses of `Number`), but `Double` is not compatible with `Integer`.

> From my understanding, int num will be implicitly converted to double

When the target is `double`, yes, the number will be promoted. But if the target is `Double`, the compiler refuses to do this implicitly (it would have to box your `int` to `Integer` before making it a `Double`, and that fails there).

If you want a quick fix, you can use `double` as the type for `num`:

```
for (double num: nums) {
    temp.add(num);
}
```

Comment: In that case, shouldn't error show up as "Integer cannot be converted to Double" instead of "int cannot be converted to Double"?

Comment: @weijia_yu It doesn't matter, does it? I've typed the steps that the compiler *would* take to make the call compatible, but that is not what it does. There's simply no relationship between `int` and `Double`, and that's what the compiler reports. Further, wouldn't it be confusing if the compiler said `Integer cannot be converted to Double`? You would surely wonder where you'd typed `Integer`.

Comment: very well explained @ernest_k !

Answer (score 0):

Definitely true since the signature method `boolean add(E e);` in `List` interface uses a generic type declaration.

Thus, if you already declare `List<Double>` type, then all elements should be implicitly implied as same type of `Double`, especially the error will be thrown at `compiling time`.

See more the specification of `List` interface at https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html

To fix the issue, just use explicitly casting to double

```
temp.add((double)num);
```

Best,

Answer (score 0):

```
public void test(int[] nums) {
    List<Double> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int num: nums) {
        temp.add(num * 1.0);
    }
}
```

OR

```
public void test(int[] nums) {
    List<Double> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    for (double num: nums) {
        temp.add(num);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> From my understanding, `int num` will be implicitly converted to `double`

**Not implicitly**, but **only when we specify** the compiler to convert by either **casting** or **assigning**. (There are answers above which have the casting part, so I am not including an example again.) For assignment, here is one:

```
int intNumber = 0;
double doubleNumber = intNumber; //This will result in conversion from int to double
```

Answer (score -1):

you can convert int to string then convert it to double

```
 public void test(int[] nums) {
            List<Double> temp = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int num: nums) {
                temp.add(Double.valueOf(num));
            }

        }
```

Comment: An answer consisting of code with no explanation is not a good answer.  And using a String is a very poor way to convert an int to a double.  And, the String conversion isn’t necessary—`parseDouble(num)` would work just fine.